# Specify diff tolerance level for golden test files in flutter

Tags: flutter, testing, screenshot, widget-test-flutter, golden-test

The reason for doing this is explained in this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/76545)

How do we set a diff tolerance levels for the golden test ? There is already [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/77014) merged for this. But I am not sure how I use those API in my tests.

Currently, I have got a golden test matcher like this.

```
await expectLater(find.byType(MyTestWidget),
    matchesGoldenFile('my_test_widget.png'));
```

How do I set a diff tolerance levels for this test ?